# How to insert a serialized object in a postgresql DB with a pickle?

Tags: python, postgresql, pickle, psycopg2, xgboost

As suggested on the title I want to insert a xgboost object in my db. I'm using psycopg2 and postgresql.

I pickled the xgboost model with dumps in order to insert the serialized version.

```
query = "INSERT INTO reporting_ml.model (model) VALUES (%(model)s)"
cursor_dev.execute(query % {"model": pickle.dumps(model)})
```

That's what I get:

```
syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 2: ... 
\x04\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x...
```

Comment: What is the data type of the model column?

Comment: @desertnaut it's bytea

Comment: maybe `pickle.dumps(model).decode()` ?

Comment: Solution found : cursor_dev.execute(query, (pickle.dumps(model),))

Comment: @TammemSa Care to explain the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Some people asked to explain [@Tammem Sa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6387238/tammem-sa)'s solution.
By looking [Psycopg's](https://www.psycopg.org/) official [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters):

> Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or
> string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query
> string. Not even at gunpoint.

We see that this is formation issue.

They specifically quote:

> Because of the difference, sometime subtle, between the data types
> representations, a naïve approach to query strings composition, such
> as using Python strings concatenation, is a recipe for terrible
> problems:

Followed by an example:

```
>>> SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES ('%s');" # NEVER DO THIS
>>> data = ("O'Reilly", )
>>> cur.execute(SQL % data) # THIS WILL FAIL MISERABLY
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Reilly"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES ('O'Reilly')
                                          ^
```

Per documentation, the correct (and one and only) way to pass variables in SQL command is using second argument of the `execute()` method:

```
>>> SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" # Note: no quotes
>>> data = ("O'Reilly", )
>>> cur.execute(SQL, data) # Note: no % operator
```

My additional two cents:

For tensors or vectors, preferable data type for column is Bytea.